# What is the maximum (unloaded) range of the Beluga XL?

Tags: aircraft-performance, range, airbus-beluga

Airbus states that the range of the Beluga XL is [4000 km](https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/press-releases/en/2019/11/belugaxl-receives-easa-type-certification.html) at maximum payload. Does anyone have a figure (or estimate) for it's maximum range with no payload?

Answer (score 5):

For an estimate, we can use the [Brequet range equation](https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node98.html):

$range = V\cdot t_f 
= \frac{L}{D} \times I_{sp} \times \ln\left(\frac{W_i}{W_f}\right) $

with:

- $V$: optimal velocity
- $t_f$: flight time
- $L$: lift
- $D$: drag
- $I_{sp}$:  propulsion efficiency
- $W_i$: initial weight
- $W_f$: final weight

Assuming the lift to drag ratio $\left(\frac{L}{D}\right)$ and the propulsion efficiency will stay constant, the range will depend on the ratio of initial and final weight.

$range = C \times \ln\left(\frac{W_i}{W_f}\right)$

In case the aircraft departs with the maximum payload, the weight is:

$W_i = W_{oe} + W_{payload} + W_{fuel} = W_{mto}$

- $W_{oe}$: operating empty weight: 127 500 kgf
- $W_{payload}$:  payload weight: 51 000 kgf
- $W_{mto}$: maximum take-off weight: 227 000 kgf
- $W_{fuel}$: fuel weight =  $W_{mto} - W_{payload}-W_{oe}$ = 48 500 kgf

The final weight at maximum range is then: 
$W_f = W_{oe} + W_{payload}$

Filling in the numbers we find:

4000 km = $C \times \ln\left(\frac{\textrm{227 000}}{\textrm{127 500 + 51 000}}\right)$

That means $C \approx \textrm{16 640}$ for the Beluga XL.

If we now remove the payload and take-off with the same amount of fuel, we find:

- $W_i$ = 176 000 kgf
- $W_f$ = 127 500 kgf
- $range \approx \textrm{16 640} \times \ln\left(\frac{\textrm{176 000}}{\textrm{127 500}}\right) \approx 5365$km

But that is just removing the payload without adding fuel. Of course we can now bring more fuel on board without exceeding the maximum take-off weight.

The fuel capacity of the Beluga XL is 73000 kg (source:[Aircraft Characteristics
Airport And Maintenance Planning Beluga XL manual](http://www.airbus.com/content/dam/corporate-topics/publications/backgrounders/techdata/aircraft_characteristics/Airbus-Commercial-Aircraft-AC-BelugaXL.pdf)). This changes the numbers to:

- $W_i$ = 200 500 kgf
- $W_f$ = 127 500 kgf
- $range \approx \textrm{16 640} \times \ln\left(\frac{\textrm{200 500}}{\textrm{127 500}}\right) \approx 7530$km

So the Beluga can fly approximately 7500 km when empty, enough to cross the Atlantic from Toulouse, even if there is normal headwind.

Answer (score 1):

It can travel 4259 kilometers or 2647 miles loaded, but I am not sure if Airbus would have a need to publicly document the information of the unloaded range - I doubt this information is accessible.

Comment: Why dismiss the case of positioning the aircraft empty? If it takes 3 hops to get from A to B loaded, it may take two legs, or maybe only one, to get from B to A empty.